# Number verification - if it is number, eponential values, it should pass otherwise it should fail

Tags: java, regex

I am using `^[-+]?[0-9]*\\.?[0-9]+([eE][-+]?[0-9]+)?$` this regular expression, its working fine for all cases. But for values like `123E104` it failing to validate.

I guess `123E104` is not exponential value. Since `123E104` is invalid exponential value. result should be false or not match

Comment: Why don't you use the classes `Double` and `Long`?

Comment: Works fine when I try that input. (Also, "its working fine for all cases"? Weird thing to say when the very next line is a case where it apparently doesn't work.)

Comment: Your regex matches the example you say does not match. See [live demo](http://rubular.com/r/i0PaS0TAFJ)

Answer (score 1):

123E+104 is actually a common way for JavaScript and probably languages to denote a string representation of a large exponent.

Answer (score 1):

Try

```
^[-+]?[0-9]*(\\.[0-9]*)?([eE][-+]?[0-9]+)?$
```

You didn't take account of the case of scientific formats without specified fractions.

Note that this regex recorginzes numbers like 123.E14. if you do not want decimal points without an explicit fraction specified, replace the quantifier for the fraction part, ie.

```
^[-+]?[0-9]*(\\.[0-9]+)?([eE][-+]?[0-9]+)?$
```

Answer (score 1):

Your regex is actually too clever - the trick with an asterisk before the dot to let it match numbers that start in a dot has actually backfired. The problem is, the `*` is a *greedy* quantifier, so if some digits have been matched before the dot, there would be nothing left for the `+` after the second group of digits.

The fix is very simple - make the first `*` *reluctant* by adding a question mark after it:

```
^[-+]?[0-9]*?\\.?[0-9]+([eE][-+]?[0-9]+)?$
//          ^
```

After this change, the `123` in front of `E` would be split between `[0-9]*?` and `[0-9]+`, leading to a match.

```
// This returns true:
Pattern.matches("^[-+]?[0-9]*?\\.?[0-9]+([eE][-+]?[0-9]+)?$", "123E104")
```

[Demo on ideone.](http://ideone.com/tHSw5F)

Comment: das gud explanation. i always thought `?` meant zero, or one (optional), is that right?

Comment: @JoeHabadas `?` by itself means zero or one; `?` that follows `*`, i.e. `*?`, means "zero or more, with an option to backtrack if necessary".

Answer (score 0):

123E104 is invalid? 123E104 should mean 123 x (10 ^ 104)